# Log off citrix session

Tags: citrix, xenapp

I want to terminate a session hosted in xen app server. When i pass the following parameter to execute on command line  such as

/username:TestUser /domain:TestDomina /password:xxxxyyyz /cmdline:logoff  using shell api ?

The wfc command line usgae pop up comes up. DOes it mean that we cannot log off using the command line option in wfc ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To logoff the current session from the app the user is running you can use the following.

```
WTSLogoffSession(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, false)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383836%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I am trying to achieve the following. From the user application , send a command to the application server to log off / terminate the session. Also , how can i let the application server know to terminate the session programmatically ? I appreciate your response.

Comment: I updated the answer based on your feedback, WTSLogoffSession allows you to logoff the session.